# How to delete a SQL Server local security group on Windows 10 Home using powershell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, windows-10

I am trying to uninstall Microsoft SQL Server from my local machine. Uninstall instructions say one must delete all local security groups for SQL Server components *before* uninstalling, however I cannot figure how to do this on Windows 10 Home. I have found online two ways of doing this, but neither has worked.

The first way is through '*Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Computer Management > Local Users and Groups*'. Because I have Home edition, the 'Local Users and Groups' option does not seem to be available so I cannot delete anything this way. Running MCM.exe and trying to add the respective snap-in doesn't work either (error says "This snap-in cannot be used with this edition of Windows...").

The second way is through PowerShell. If I use the cmdlet:

```
Get-LocalGroup
```

I can see a SQL Sever group called:

```
SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$<computername>.
```

However, if I try to delete it using the cmdlet:

```
Remove-LocalGroup -Name "SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$<computername>"
```

I get an error message saying that no such group exists, as it cannot read what follow the dollar sign ($). Since -Name doesn't accept wildcards here, I don't know how to tell PowerShell to delete this group.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there another way to do this?

Sorry if this is a newbie question, but I am currently at a loss and cannot find any other ideas how to do this.

Thank you.

Comment: Try using single quote `'` instead of double quote `"`.

Comment: @vonPryz Heh, I feel dumb for not knowing this. You're right and it worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Remove-LocalGroup -Name 'SQLServer2005SQLBrowserUser$<computername>'
```

The problem is that variable names are expanded inside a double-quoted string. Using single quotes prevents PowerShell from parsing the string and thinking `$<computername>` is a variable.